# Symfony2 Custom Repository, Lazy Loading and Proxy Objects

Tags: repository, doctrine-orm, symfony, dql

I'm having some trouble pulling up relationed objects from my database using Doctrine2 in Symfony2.  I have a custom repository with the following function:

```
public function getOrder($id) {
    $DQL = 'SELECT request, orderer
    FROM OrderRequestBundle:OrderRequest request
    JOIN request.orderer orderer
    WHERE request.id = :id';

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($DQL)
                ->setParameter('id', $id)
                ->setMaxResults(1);
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

...but for some reason when I run this function I get back a Proxy object for an OrderRequest object rather than a real instance of OrderRequest, am I missing something?  It seems that Doctrine2 loves lazy-loading and I can't seem to get it up off its ass and fetch objects for me.

UPDATE:
I'm attempting to simply display the information in a Twig template with the code below:

```
$order = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('OrderRequestBundle:OrderRequest')
    ->getOrder($id);

return $this->render('OrderRequestBundle:Admin:view.html.twig', array('order' => $order));
```

Where Twig calls information about the 'order' variable as so:

```
{{ order.quantity }}
```

...but I just end up with this error:

```
Item "quantity" for "Array" does not exist in "OrderRequestBundle:Admin:view.html.twig" at line 5
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want a proxy instance?

Comment: I'm trying to grab information about the OrderRequest object to display on a page (via a Twig template), but I keep getting the error that the properties of the object don't exist.  I'll update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Given your edit, the problem isn't proxy objects at all, it's how you're using your $query object.

`$query->getResult()` will return an array of results. In an instance like this where you're limiting the result set to a max of 1 row, it'll return an array with one entry, but still an array. Twig chokes on this when trying to use accessor methods, naturally.

What you'll want to do is use `$query->getSingleResult()` instead. Note that Doctrine will throw a non-unique result exception if the query returns more than one row, so you need to be sure to use it with `setMaxResults(1)` like you're doing if the query can possibly return multiple results.

**END UPDATE**

From the documentation on [reference proxies](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/configuration.html#reference-proxies):

> Here $item is actually an instance of the proxy class that was
>   generated for the Item class but your code does not need to care. In
>   fact it **should not care**. Proxy objects should be transparent to your
>   code.

Emphasis theirs. Proxies should be transparent to your code, and exist to improve performance where possible; however, if you have a pressing need to eager-load part of the query, you can either set the fetch mode in your entity configuration file, or check out [this section](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html?highlight=eager#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql) of the docs:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT u FROM MyProject\User u");
$query->setFetchMode("MyProject\User", "address", "EAGER");
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you!  I presumed that $query->getSingleResult() would produce the same results as $query->setMaxResults(1) followed by $query->getResult().  This did the trick.  :D

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine2 *always* returns proxy objects from repository queries. These extend your entity classes and for all intents and purposes, are the same thing.

The proxies simply enable your entities to support lazy-loading of related entities (among other things).

See http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html?highlight=proxy#entity-object-graph-traversal